# Cannot save img tag to Note filed with RichEditMode

Tags: 2010, picture, multiline-text-field, richhtmlfield, image-upload

I have custom page with MultiLine TextBox control. I linked this field with [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/) scripts for adding pictures. Then I should store field's content into Note field with RichEditMode in SP13 list.

I user code below :

```
SPList answers = SPContext.Current.Web.GetListByUrl(BuiltInList.Answers);    
answer[BuiltInFields.Answers.Description] = tbxAnswer.Text;
answer.Update();
```

At the second row I have

```
<img src=\"../../Documents/fire.PNG\" alt=\"5555\" width=\"35\" height=\"36\" />
```

But after update at the third row:

```
<img alt=\"5555\" width=\"35\" height=\"36\" />
```

Consequently, I have not image view, only empty tag.

How to save img tag with src data?

Answer (score 0):

It was need to set TinyMCE attributes with values:

```
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    convert_urls: true,
```